# Remove strings from an array if they match regex in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a array that contains different strings. I want to remove all the nonwords in the string that match the regex.

```
myarray = ['I want to play football , not watch it yeah:', 'Leeds: play the / worse football']
myregex = /\W+\s/gi
```

I want to remove all the nonwords that match the regex but keeping the string the same including the spaces.

```
  newarray = ['I want to play football not watch it yeah', 'Leeds play the worse football']
```

I'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: you can iterate the array, apply your regex and use .splice() function

Comment: Note that your current regex won't match the `:` at the end of your first  string

Comment: @Gonzalo.- splice definitely isn't the right method to take chunks out of a string.

Comment: sorry, I read to remove the entire string from the array. Then replace is the answer

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the array using a string [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

```
myregex = /\W+\s/gi;
newarray = myarray.map(function (str) {
  return str.replace(myregex, '');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this RegEx:

```
(\s[^\w ]|[^\w ])
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on RegExr**](https://regex101.com/r/sP7dF0/1)</kbd>

You would use it on your array using [`.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) like so:

```
MyRegex = /(\s[^\w ]|[^\w ])/gi;
NewArray = MyArray.map(function(string) {
    return string.replace(MyRegex, '')
})
```

---

```js
MyArray = ['I want to play football , not watch it yeah:', 'Leeds: play the / worse football']

MyRegex = /(\s[^\w ]|[^\w ])/gi

NewArray = MyArray.map(function(string) {
    var NewString = string.replace(MyRegex, '')
    document.write(NewString + '<br>')
    return NewString
})
```

Comment: how do I modify the regex to not remove words that contains the symbol @ . For example "@regex"